# SQL query select sum point

Tags: sql-server

i got 2 table [image: XemDiem]

[image: BieuDo]

i want to write sql which select score May Month, 2019 year , trimester 2 
this is my code to select score from May

```
 SELECT
    XD.user_Id, XD.[Name],XD.viTri,XD.sex ,SUM(BD.Point) as pointM
 FROM
    XemDiem XD
 INNER JOIN
    BieuDo BD On BD.user_Id = XD.user_Id
WHERE Month(BD.[DateTime]) = 5 
GROUP BY
    XD.user_Id, XD.[Name],XD.viTri ,XD.sex
```

the result should be look like this 
[image]

Comment: What is your logic for obtaining expected results? Also, please show sample data as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select XD.user_Id, XD.[Name],XD.viTri,XD.sex
sum(case when MONTH(convert(datetime,BD.Date,5)) = 5 and Year(convert(datetime,BD.Date,5)) = 2019 then BD.Point else 0 end) as monthP,
sum(case when MONTH(convert(datetime,BD.Date,5)) >= 4 and MONTH(convert(datetime,BD.Date,5)) <= 6 and Year(convert(datetime,BD.Date,5)) = 2019 then BD.Point else 0 end) as trimesterP
sum(case when MONTH(convert(datetime,BD.Date,5)) = 5 and Year(convert(datetime,BD.Date,5)) = 2019 then BD.Point else 0 end) as yearP
from info
    XemDiem XD
 INNER JOIN
    BieuDo BD On BD.user_Id = XD.user_Id
WHERE Month(BD.[DateTime]) = 5 
GROUP BY
    XD.user_Id, XD.[Name],XD.viTri ,XD.sex
```